# Faixa preta por cima da imagem

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Como faço]

Boa Noite, como faço para fazer essa tarja preta por cima de uma imagem com bootstrap e css, se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n73xdf6s/1/). Basta usar rgba para o background, ou pode usar uma imagem de 1 pixel com transparência (png), se repetindo no  background via css.